Would it be possible for a somewhat distant bianary star system to have a planet orbiting their barycenter within both their orbits?
There are 2 stars in a binary system, 268 AU apart from each other. Both are about 1 solar mass.
Would  it be possible for some  planet to be orbiting their barycenter (the center mass of both starts), within the orbits of both starts around the barycenter?
The details of the planet itself are largely irrelevant other than it has be be able to have a moon of sufficient mass to reach hydrostatic equilibrium. I don't really care what else it might be.
Please say if there's any important details i'm missing here.

When you say orbiting around the barycenter how big an orbit are you talking about? It might be more stable if it actually doesn't orbit but is at the barycenter, but sounds pretty impossible for it to naturally occur to be stable. Any actual orbit I think would be unstable and eventually it would escape or get captured by one of the stars.

@HSharp i don't really care as long as it's closer to the barycentre than the stars

Approximating a distribution of masses with their barycenter only works when "sufficiently away" from said masses.
Being between those two masses doesn't qualify as "sufficiently away".
By using the barycenter you are replacing the sum of each force vector with the single force vector produced by the total mass of the system in the barycenter. When you are between the masses, some of those forces cancel each other because they pull in opposite directions, while you can't cancel masses.

No, but something else might be
As has been mentioned, the barycenter of two bodies is used to approximate the effects they both have on something. It is only accurate over long distances, and being in between the two stars is about as close as you can get. It won't orbit the barycenter.
However, there is a possible solution: Have the planet in the L4/L5 point. It's not exactly in between the stars, but its kinda close. They are also stable, meaning it is possible for a planet to end up there. Plus, it would mean the stars appear to not move, which is similar to what would happen if the planet is between them. I'm not sure what you want the planet to be in the middle for, but the L4/L5 points might also satisfy that.
Unfortunately, they are only stable if one of the stars is ~25 times the mass of the other, which means they can't both be 1 solar mass, which is a drawback, but it is close to what you are going for(I think).
